# Point or "reset" variables in C

Tags: c, variables

If I have some thing like:

```
printf("\nEnter 2 numbers: \n");
scanf(" %d %d", &a, &b);
    add (a,b)

    int a,b;

{
printf ("%d", a+b);
}
```

Then want to run the block again, but with new variables of "nothing" like when the first printf statement is entered.  Any suggestions?

Comment: make it as function and call function bunch of times ;) each time your variables are "destroyed", "deleted".

Comment: you are using a and b before declaring it. Your compiler will not allow it, anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all avoid using `K&R` C syntax

```
/* Your function 
add (a,b)
int a,b;
{
   printf ("Sum = %d\n", a+b);
}
*/

/* Use following style*/
void add (int a,int b)
{
  printf ("Sum = %d\n", a+b);
}

int main()
{

int i,a,b; // Declare variables
int n=5; // Call it say n=5 times

for(i=0;i<n;i++)  //Use a for loop to iterate for n times
{ 
  printf("\nEnter 2 numbers: \n");
  if(scanf(" %d %d", &a, &b)==2) // with 2 new inputs
    add(a,b); //Call your add function
 }
}
```

Comment: If you advice OP to avoid K&R syntax, then why are you still using it in your sample code? Also, `int i,a,b; // Initialize variables` - that's not initialization.